# Use .htaccess to configure subdomains serve content from folders rather than from the root domain

Tags: htaccess, subdomain, multiple-domains

Here is site http://www.glassnow.com.au/
With 3 subdomains:

- brisbane.glassnow.com.au
- goldcoast.glassnow.com.au
- sunshinecoast.glassnow.com.au

Here is htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.glassnow.com.au
RewriteRule ^brisbane/(.*)$ http://brisbane.glassnow.com.au/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.glassnow.com.au
RewriteRule ^sunshinecoast/(.*)$ http://sunshinecoast.glassnow.com.au/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.glassnow.com.au
RewriteRule ^goldcoast/(.*)$ http://goldcoast.glassnow.com.au/$1 [L,R=301]


# redirect from non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^glassnow.com.au$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.glassnow.com.au/$1 [R=301,L]


RewriteRule ^index\.html$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index\.html$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /[^?\s]+\.html
RewriteRule (.*)\.html$ /$1/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*)/$ $1.html [L]

# Remove trailing slash:
RewriteRule (.*)/$ $1 [L]

# Now test without the trailing slash:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html [QSA,L]


<IfModule mod_expires.c>
# Enable expirations
ExpiresActive On 
# Default directive
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
# My favicon
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
# Images
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
# CSS
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
# Javascript
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
Header unset ETag
</ifModule>
FileETag None
```

Problem is that any of those subdomains points not to its directory but to the root folder. How to configure it correctly?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here is not to do with your *.htaccess* redirections, but to do with your *VirtualHost* configurations in Apache's *httpd.conf* configuration file - this is how Apache knows which folder to direct requests to for processing.

```
# Default Site - Blank
<VirtualHost *.80>
 ServerName localhost
 DocumentRoot /var/www/default
</VirtualHost>

# Parent Website
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName glassnow.com.au
 ServerAlias www.glassnow.com.au
 DocumentRoot /var/www/glassnow-www
</VirtualHost>

# Brisbane Website
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName brisbane.glassnow.com.au
 DocumentRoot /var/www/glassnow-brisbane
</VirtualHost>

# Gold Coast Website
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName goldcoast.glassnow.com.au
 DocumentRoot /var/www/glassnow-goldcoast
</VirtualHost>

# Sunshine Coast Website
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName sunshinecoast.glassnow.com.au
 DocumentRoot /var/www/glassnow-sunshinecoast
</VirtualHost>
```

Your respective webroot folders would then be those as defined with the *DocumentRoot* directives for each VirtualHost.

Comment: I have no access to the host configuration :(

Comment: If your hosting is Cpanel its under addon domains. It can also be done in Plesk.

Comment: @Tsiskreli, presume you're on a shared hosting setup then if you have no access to httpd.conf, what type of control panel system are you using?

Answer (score 0):

[richhallstoke](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/35875/richhallstoke)'s for configuring virtual hosts is usually the easiest approach.   If for some reason you don't have access to configuration to let you do that, it *can* be done in .htaccess.   Additional rewrite rules would be needed:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^brisbane.glassnow.com.au$
RewriteRule (.*) /brisbane/$1 [L]    

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^goldcoast.glassnow.com.au$
RewriteRule (.*) /goldcoast/$1 [L]    

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sunshinecoast.glassnow.com.au$
RewriteRule (.*) /sunshinecoast/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I have no access to the host config. This has to be added aditionally or instead?

Comment: this doesn't work :(

Comment: I edited it to put in some slashes.   Also, try it in different places.  It might have to come before some of your other rules.

Comment: in both cases before and after top redirect rules getting error 500